# Swift Ambiguous use of 'subscript'

Tags: swift, subscript

I had recently added new pods to my project and updated the previous ones, this code had all worked before and now I am getting "Ambiguous use of 'subscript'" I have been checking other answers and it seems like the way I have it currently set up is the correct way. I am not sure why all of a sudden these lines of code would get flagged as errors.

```
databaseRef.child("following").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (postsSnapshot) in
    let posts = postsSnapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
    for (_, post) in posts {
        for (_, postInfo) in post as! [String: AnyObject] {

            if let followingID = postInfo["uid"] as? String {
                for each in self.following {
                    if each == followingID {

                        guard let uid = postInfo["uid"] as! String? else {return}
                        guard let name = postInfo["businessName"] as! String? else {return}
                        guard let address = postInfo["businessStreet"] as! String? else {return}
                        guard let state = postInfo["businessState"] as! String? else {return}
                        guard let city = postInfo["businessCity"] as! String? else {return}

                        let data = ["uid":postInfo["uid"] as! String, "businessName":postInfo["businessName"] as! String, "businessStreet":postInfo["businessStreet"] as! String, "businessState":postInfo["businessState"] as! String, "businessCity":postInfo["businessCity"] as! String,"businessZIP":postInfo["businessZIP"] as! String, "businessPhone":postInfo["businessPhone"] as! String, "businessLatitude":postInfo["businessLatitude"] as! String, "businessLongitude":postInfo["businessLongitude"] as! String, "businessWebsite":postInfo["businessWebsite"] as! String, "facebookURL":postInfo["facebookURL"] as! String, "foursquareURL":postInfo["foursquareURL"] as! String, "googleURL":postInfo["googleURL"] as! String, "instagramURL":postInfo["instagramURL"] as! String, "snapchatURL":postInfo["snapchatURL"] as! String, "twitterURL":postInfo["twitterURL"] as! String, "yelpURL":postInfo["yelpURL"] as! String]
```

Comment: Maybe unrelated but the syntax `as! String?` (force unwrap an optional to an optional) is nonsense. In a `guard` expression you are going to conditionally downcast  the value so write `as? String`. And later use the unwrapped values: `let data = ["uid":uid, "businessName": name, ...`

Comment: ok thanks for that

Comment: Still doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your use of `AnyObject`. `postInfo` is being declared as `AnyObject` but then you attempt to use it like a dictionary, hence the error.

If `post` is a dictionary of dictionaries, then declare is as such:

Change:

```
for (_, postInfo) in post as! [String: AnyObject] {
```

to:

```
for (_, postInfo) in post as! [String: [String: AnyObject]] {
```

This will change `postInfo` to be `[String: AnyObject]` instead of `AnyObject`.